# Parse all variables at function declaration instead of run-time

Tags: javascript, variable-declaration

I want to attach an event coming from a string. The problem I am having is that the function names are not passing in as strings but rather being compiled when the function is called which is resulting in an undefined variable error (temp).

```
function someFun(arg) {
   alert(arg) ;
}

  temp[0] = "someFunc(test)" ;//this would be a sample of the incoming HTML
  var x = 0 ;
  while(temp[x] != '') {
    temp[x] = temp[x].replace(')','').split('(') ;//remove paranthesis and separate  func name from args
    temp[x][1] = temp[x][1].split(',') ;//turn string of args into array
    func = function() { window[temp[x][0]].apply(el,[]) ; }
    el.addEventListener('click',func,false) ;
    x++ ;
  }
```

If I dont use temp[x][0] (which would be 'someFunc') but rather pass in a string for the .apply method (in this case .apply('someFunc'...) ) directly I have no issues and the function will be called with onClick as expected. Otherwise when I click on element el I get an error that temp is not defined.

Comment: I think we need some more information on what you are trying to do, there might be a slightly different way to achieve your goals if we know more.

Comment: Im trying to send a string written like HTML would be and have my javascript parser create all the elements and add attributes + events like .innerHTML would. In this case Im trying to attach onClick events to the element el.

Comment: Please update your question with relevant code and input/output example and explain WHY you are doing what you are doing

Comment: In the incoming string that has content written like HTML, how are you specifying the onclick handler? Just with `conclick=` Can you add the sample you are working with to the question please?

Comment: i modified the code a bit to make more sense. Adding the entire thing would be a bit much but the html is coming in exactly like it would be entered as an attribute. Everything is checking out but the apply method is not compiling the variables until it is actually called so temp is going in as a variable temp instead of the string name of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im pretty sure that if you assign `temp[x][0]` to a variable before the functions are assigned it should work. Something like this

```
if (attributes._onClick) {

  temp = attributes._onClick;
  var x = 0;

  while(temp[x] != '') {

    var funcSig = temp[x].replace(')','').split('('); //remove paranthesis and separate func name from args

    var funcName = funcSig[0];
    var funcArgs = funcSig[1].split(','); //turn string of args into array

    func = function() { window[funcName].apply(el,[]); }

    el.addEventListener('click',function(){
      window[funcName].apply(el,funcArgs); }
    ,false);

    x++;
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Kind of crazy. Thanks a ton I would have been trying to figure out why it wasnt compiling forever. Any idea why the string has to be assigned to a separate variable first?

Comment: @MagicLasso Can you recheck my answer I've amended your initial code so its clear what's going on.

Comment: @MagicLasso Something to do with closures and the scope of the used variable - much cleaner to write like I've shown

Comment: Yep thats right. I dont know why I left the func variable in there though. And it works fine now. Thanks again.

Comment: +1 on the sentence `Im pretty sure that if you assign temp[x][0] to a variable before the functions are assigned it should work`